# Obtener valor de "Entry" (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

buenas tardes y buenas noches, estoy iniciando a programar con python y quiero hacer que una variable que tome un valor tipo entero de una caja de texto de `tkinter`, el caso es que siempre que pido que me imprima un numero me sale 64 independientemente del numero siempre me imprime 64. Agradezco su ayuda, aquí esta el código por si lo pueden solucionar gracias.

```
from re import X
from struct import pack
import tkinter

ventana=tkinter.Tk()
x=tkinter.Entry(ventana)
x.pack()
thp = int(X)

def go ():
  print(thp)


boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, command=go)
boton.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tienes tres errores, el primero es que estas utilizando `X` (Mayúscula, importada del módulo `re`) y no `x` (Minúscula, que tiene el valor de un `Entry`)

El segundo error es que debes obtener el valor al oprimir el botón, es decir, adentro de la función `go` ya que si obtienes el valor justo al declarar `x` no tiene nada y te mandará error que no puede convertirlo a `int` (`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`)

El tercero es que para obtener el valor de un `Entry` debes utilizar el método `get()`.

```
from re import X
from struct import pack
import tkinter

ventana=tkinter.Tk()
x=tkinter.Entry(ventana)
x.pack()

def go ():
    thp = int(x.get())
    print(thp)


boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, command=go)
boton.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Te recomiendo que al declarar variables no utilices nombres reservados o similares a nombres reservados o que sean parte de los módulos que estás importando para evitar este tipo de errores.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

ventana=Tk()
r1= StringVar()
x=Entry(ventana, texvariable=r1)
x.pack()

def go ():
    thp = int(x.get())
    print(thp)
    return r1.self(thp)

boton = Button(ventana, command=go)
boton.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].